# What can I do to make this confirmation dialog only change inventory if the person says they are sure, but to cancel if they click cancel?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, confirmation

When I open a dialog box which asks for confirmation of deleting a part in the inventory the part gets deleted even if I click cancel. I am not sure what to change in order to address this. I considered conditionals but wasn't sure how to implement the conditional dependent upon the response from the Confirmation Dialog Box.

```java
@FXML
void AddProductDel(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Are you Sure?");
    alert.setContentText("This will delete the Part");
    alert.showAndWait();

    stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    Part part = addProductDelTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    newproduct.deleteAssociatedPart(part);
    addProductDelTable.setItems(newproduct.getAssociatedParts());
}
```

Comment: That does help a lot. That addresses the issue of getting a conditional result. I would also need help understanding how to make the "Part part = addProductDelTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    newproduct.deleteAssociatedPart(part);
    addProductDelTable.setItems(newproduct.getAssociatedParts());"                     the conditional response. Is it possible to just insert all that into the conditional in the form that is return in the example provided in the primary answer in the link you provided?

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions, please!